# WPF usercontrol command binding to window viewmodel

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm

I have a Window which contains UserControl1 and UserControl2. These user controls have their own viewmodels. Also, these user controls use UserControl3 to display data. So, when UserControl1 uses UserControl3 the UserControl3 has the same viewmodel as UserControl1.

I have a binding in UserControl3 which I wish to call the command which is on the viewmodel of UserControl1.

But I can't find a way to make it work. Any help is welcomed. Thank you very much.

Here is my binding which does not work:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.UserControl3"             
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">    
<UserControl.Resources>        
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type g:GraphNode}"> 
        <StackPanel>               
            <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="My Command" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl3}}}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>               
            <Grid>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Data}"/>                      
            </Grid> 
        </StackPanel>             
    </DataTemplate>       
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in my app:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type g:GraphNode}">
        <StackPanel Tag="{Binding}">
            <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="My Command" Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The key is that ContextMenus are on a different window, so you can't access datacontexts like you usually do.
You will have to adapt this so that the object containing the `Command` you seek is set as the Tag of the `StackPanel` (which is the `PlacementTarget` of your `ContextMenu`).